# Changing the default color of TabItems (MahAppsMetro)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mahapps.metro

I am using `MahAppsMetro` and have a `TabControl` - actually the inactive Tabs should have a Gray Foreground and become Black on MouseOver. Somehow they are Black the whole time..
This is how I use the TabControl:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Name="MW_Window" x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
Title="Example" Icon="/Example;component/pics/Example.ico" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="665.5" Width="759" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" NonActiveWindowTitleBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" NonActiveGlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" NonActiveBorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}">
     <Grid>
         <Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl  Name="TabControl1"  Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <TabItem Header="Dashboard" Name="Dashboard">
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,114,0,0" Name="RadioButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True" Width="64" Content="" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
                    <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,138,0,0" Name="RadioButton2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" />
                    <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,162,0,0" Name="RadioButton3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" />
                    <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,185,0,0" Name="RadioButton4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Options" Name="Options">
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" >

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Info" Name="Info">
                 <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Admin" Name="Admin">
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" >

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="FM" Name="SuperAdmin">
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" >

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

I use my own xaml-File (copied the original one and changed the Basic-Colors) but the rest is the same.

[How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbS7J.png)

[How it should be (Info is black because of MouseOver)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZdDM.png)

How can I now set the default Foreground-Color for my unselected tabitems back to gray?

**Edit:**
Was able to find the issue:

I removed the BaseLight.xaml from the applications MergedDictionaries - then it was no more working - after adding it again it was working again.

*Before:*

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="LiquidStyle_Classic.xaml" />
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

*After:*

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="LiquidStyle_Classic.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: I ended up copying the whole style template from the git source code and making changes, then using that style in my application. There might be a better way though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define a style for `TabItem` with custom trigger.
Add the following markup in your Grid:

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            From="Gray" To="Black" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            From="Black" To="Gray" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: well this causes that when I MouseOver on one TabItem everything turns black - all other tabitems and even the labels I have in grids of the tab items..

Comment: For me it works. I have already tested it. However you can show your full markup, maybe something weird is happening.

Comment: Full markup would be too much I think.
I added RadioButtons for the Dashboard tabitem - for example the conent of them changes.

Comment: This looks like it is changing the foreground color resource which could be shared with everything (can't see all your xaml).

Comment: added a solution to my post - thanks or your help anyway!